# Inversion de 'Il y en a un'

Tags: grammaire, questions, inversion

Comment on peut inverser la phrase

> Il y en a un.

Pour faire une question. Y-en-a-t-il?

Comment: Il y en a **un**. => Y en a-t-il **un** ?

Comment: Tu as écrit la réponse dans ta question (sauf les tirets). A moins que je n'ai pas compris la question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Y en a-t-il"* is not the exact interrogative form of *"Il y en a un"*.

---

**Question** :

> Y en a-t-il ?

**Réponses** :

> Oui.

... ***il y en a***, mais on ne sait pas combien (au moins un, mais peut-être plus).

> Non.

... il n'y en a aucun.

---

**Question** :

> Y en a-t-il un ?

**Réponses** :

> Oui.

... ***il y en a un*** (mais pas plus).

> Non.

... il n'y en a aucun.

---

**Question** :

> N'y en a-t-il qu'un ?

**Réponses** :

> Oui.

... il n'y en a qu'un (et pas plus).

> Non.

... il n'y en a aucun ou il y en a plusieurs (au moins deux).

Answer (score 3):

It s like this (just 2 dashes)

Y en **a-t-il**

Comment: *"Y en a-t-il"* is not the interrogative form of *"il y en a un"*, please edit (and add question mark).